# How to connect from localhost webapp (ethers) to remix VM?

Tags: remix, metamask

With Remix IDE, I can deploy Smart Contracts and interact with them, with Remix VM, without deploying on testnets.

When I want to interact with Smart Contracts developed on Remix IDE, from a webapp (e.g. with ethers), I deploy them in a testnet (public layer, not localhost like Remix VM) and later on I connect to the testnet RPC node and contract address, with the help of Metamask.

Can I connect directly to Remix VM connection from my localhost webapp?

[From documentation I can get that Remix VM connection RPC URL](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run.html#more-about-external-http-provider) is:

```
http://localhost:8545
```

I cannot find the Chain ID in documentation, but I have developed a simple function to get it, which returns "1" value.

```
function getChainID() public view returns (uint256){
        return block.chainid;
    }
```

The point is that Metamask does not accept that network as valid (http://localhost:8545 with chainID: 1). How could I connect to Remix VM chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you wanna connect to Remix VM? You need to do the other way around, I guess.

- Spin up a local node using hardhat or anvil. It should be running in http://localhost:8545.
- Connect remix to the localnode by choosing the hardhat or anvil provider.
- Now you can deploy contracts to your localnode using Remix.
- Also you can connect your metamask and frontend app to your localnode to test the transactions.

This is the simplest approach.

Comment: While it is also a simple approach, it requires to run the hardhat node on terminal. Using Remix VM (if possible) you could avoid even running hardhat node.

Comment: If you want to connect to a node, the node should expose a RPC server to accept requests. Remix VM runs its sandbox blockchain in the browser and it doesn't expose a RPC server. So you can connect Remix with external providers, but not vice versa.